# Numpy: how to construct a big diagonal array(matrix) from arbitrary length of small arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working on a problem statement which requires to construct a big diagonal matrix from the different length of small array :

**First Case**

```
import numpy as np
matrix_a = np.random.uniform(1,9,[2,2])
matrix_b = np.random.uniform(1,9,[3,3])
matrix_c = np.random.uniform(1,9,[5,5])
```

How to join them diagonally?

**Second case**
When matrix shape are not n x n how to join them diagonally?

```
import numpy as np
matrix_a = np.random.uniform(1,9,[2,9])
matrix_b = np.random.uniform(1,9,[3,1])
matrix_c = np.random.uniform(1,9,[10,5])
```

I tried with this code :

```
def diag_block_mat_boolindex(L):
    shp = L[0].shape
    mask = np.kron(np.eye(len(L)), np.ones(shp))==1
    out = np.zeros(np.asarray(shp)*len(L),dtype=int)
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(L).ravel()
    return out
```

But it expects all array should be same size.

Comment: what do you mean by join them diagonally, pls provide some input and what output do you expect

Comment: Is it what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895154/scipy-block-diag-of-a-list-of-matrices

Answer (score 1):

My solution works even for non-square arrays and each array can have
its own shape.

In order to get "not to wide" result, I defined source arrays as:

```
matrix_a = np.array([
    [3.47, 8.07, 8.15],
    [7.89, 8.59, 9.19]])
matrix_b = np.array([
    [3.81, 4.65, 5.96],
    [4.98, 1.45, 7.94],
    [5.68, 5.32, 3.81]])
matrix_c = np.array([
    [1.67, 6.84, 5.52, 8.79, 5.71],
    [7.68, 8.20, 7.52, 3.09, 2.17],
    [6.09, 7.70, 3.57, 8.67, 8.97],
    [4.29, 2.00, 4.45, 3.13, 4.78],
    [6.63, 1.19, 4.96, 1.15, 2.75]])
```

Note that *matrix_a* has different number of rows than columns.

The function creating the diagonal block array is as follows:

```
def diag_block_mat(tList):
    blkXsize = [ tbl.shape[1] for tbl in tList ]
    outBlocks = []
    for i, tbl in enumerate(tList):
        tBefore = np.zeros((tbl.shape[0], sum(blkXsize[:i])))
        tAfter = np.zeros((tbl.shape[0], sum(blkXsize[i+1:])))
        outBlocks.append(np.hstack([tBefore, tbl, tAfter]))
    return np.vstack(outBlocks)
```

To get the result, run:

```
result = diag_block_mat([matrix_a, matrix_b, matrix_c])
```

The result is:

```
[[3.47 8.07 8.15 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [7.89 8.59 9.19 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   3.81 4.65 5.96 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   4.98 1.45 7.94 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   5.68 5.32 3.81 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.67 6.84 5.52 8.79 5.71]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   7.68 8.2  7.52 3.09 2.17]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   6.09 7.7  3.57 8.67 8.97]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   4.29 2.   4.45 3.13 4.78]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   6.63 1.19 4.96 1.15 2.75]]
```

## Edit

A shorter, although more difficult to read version of the above function is:

```
def diag_block_mat2(tList):
    blkXsize = [ tbl.shape[1] for tbl in tList ]
    return np.vstack( [ np.hstack([np.zeros((tbl.shape[0], sum(blkXsize[:i]))),
        tbl, np.zeros((tbl.shape[0], sum(blkXsize[i+1:])))])
        for i, tbl in enumerate(tList) ] )
```

Answer (score -1):

in case you want to have on big diagonal matrix, you can use `flatten()` to make them 1d and `np.hstack` to stack and finally `np.diag` to create the diagonal matrix

```
np.diag(np.hstack([matrix_a.flatten(),matrix_b.flatten(),matrix_c.flatten()]))
```

for diagonal blocks you can use `block_diag` form `scipy.linalg`

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
diag_arr = block_diag(matrix_a,matrix_b,matrix_c)
diag_arr

array([[3.90052311, 7.0255518 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [5.82145576, 1.52557976, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 5.55105741, 8.12289884, 7.39576087,        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 6.3505038 , 6.49595552, 8.82140467,        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.81498368, 2.45317746, 6.18327514,        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        2.29199651, 8.08330405, 4.97906443, 6.09044791, 3.43850224],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        3.29613236, 1.10099814, 8.24524896, 6.88402218, 1.27999627],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        8.24501287, 8.80467721, 1.63928483, 6.42174494, 4.22360478],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        1.78582001, 4.5269237 , 1.01814274, 5.92798347, 3.79980894],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,        7.14772321, 6.57307265, 5.25354726, 4.02427576, 7.99641514]])
```